# How can I save this kind of data in cakePHP 2.3?

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

First of all am using cakePHP 2.3 framework and I have created form where I also have some relationships. The good thing is that I'm able to save the data, if the fields are not in array form like below.

```
<input type="text" name="data['Academicrecord']['school'][]" />
<input type="text" name="data['Academicrecord']['award'][]" />
<input type="text" name="data['Academicrecord']['from'][]" />
<input type="text" name="data['Academicrecord']['to'][]" />
```

But I get this error when I submit the form data above.

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

Look at the info generated by the cakePHP in built debug function.

```
debug($this->request->data);

'Academicrecord' => array(
    'school' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Kansanga Primary School',
        (int) 1 => 'Tropical High School'
    ),
    'award' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'P.L.E',
        (int) 1 => 'U.C.E'
    ),
    'from' => array(
        (int) 0 => '1997',
        (int) 1 => '2003'
    ),
    'to' => array(
        (int) 0 => '2002',
        (int) 1 => '2006'
    )
)
```

On my way to solving this problem, I thought I could use the for loop to iterate the submitted items and then send them(data) to the model. Unfortunately my for loops cannot iterate the until the second row.

```
          echo  "The counts: ".count( $this->request->data['Academicrecord']['school']).'<br/>';

       for($i=0;$i<count( $this->request->data['Academicrecord']['school']);$i++){

         $this->request->data['Academicrecord']['staff_id'] = $this->Staff->id;
         echo "{$i} :".$this->request->data['Academicrecord']['school'] =   $this->request->data['Academicrecord']['school'][$i];
         echo ' '.$this->request->data['Academicrecord']['award']  =   $this->request->data['Academicrecord']['award'][$i];
         echo ' '.$this->request->data['Academicrecord']['from']   =   $this->request->data['Academicrecord']['from'][$i];
         echo ' '.$this->request->data['Academicrecord']['to']     =   $this->request->data['Academicrecord']['to'][$i];
         echo "<br/>";

           //$this->Staff->Academicrecord->save($this->request->data);
       }
```

Sample result after submitting.

The counts of rows: 2

Row 0 :Kansanga Primary School PLE 1990 2004

Comment: You need to show the executed sql, why are you hand-writing your form input names? That's basically "the problem".

Comment: @AD7six please that code is got from firebug, The  SQL code is `SQL Query: INSERT INTO `autohrms`.`academicrecords` (`school`, `award`, `from`, `to`, `staff_id`) VALUES (Array, Array, Array, Array, 56)`

Comment: Which is not surprising because your form inputs create a data structure that won't work with CakePHP's save methods. Look at [the docs for saveMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.htm) if you are trying to insert 2+ rows, else in addition to showing your code (by editing the question) you'll need to describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AD7six that is not true, not knowing how do it doesn't mean that it cannot be done.

Comment: If that structure cannot work with cakePHP there is a work around. I'm sure, I will try the foreach loop.

Comment: There isnt a work around; there is "the right way to do it" which starts with reading the documentation I already linked to.

Comment: Have you ever developed an invoice application? Imagine a situation whereby your application has a feature for adding form fields dynamically. But those fields are cloned from the existing fields e.g the item, description, unit cost and total. How could you you name the form fields to make sure they correspond with the model?

Comment: @AD7six Finally I have done it thank you a lot. I realized something I was doing wrong and cakePHP convention had something to do with it. I will write the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In loop you need to create the data like:

```
echo  "The counts: ".count( $this->request->data['Academicrecord']['school']).'<br/>';

       for($i=0;$i<count( $this->request->data['Academicrecord']['school']);$i++){

         $this->request->data['Academicrecord']['staff_id'] = $this->Staff->id;
         echo "{$i} :".$this->request->data['Academicrecord']['school'] =   $this->request->data['Academicrecord']['school'][$i];
         echo ' '.$this->request->data['Academicrecord']['award']  =   $this->request->data['Academicrecord']['award'][$i];
         echo ' '.$this->request->data['Academicrecord']['from']   =   $this->request->data['Academicrecord']['from'][$i];
         echo ' '.$this->request->data['Academicrecord']['to']     =   $this->request->data['Academicrecord']['to'][$i];
         //echo "<br/>";
         **$this->Staff->Academicrecord->create();**

         $this->Staff->Academicrecord->save($this->request->data);
       }
```

And i am not sure why you are using $this->Staff->Academicrecord instead of $this->Academicrecord.

Comment: Thank you @Vikram I use `$this->Staff->Academicrecord because of associations. Let me test by adding your suggestion. Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer from here. http://topdsoft.com/stories/view/186